# Counting files and directories in a very large subversion repository

Tags: perl, svn

Here at work, we have a rather large subversion repository. As part of our internal monitoring, we want a count of all files and directories for every revision in all our repositories.  Problem is, one of them has around 29000 revisions, and contains around 300000 directories, with almost 4 million files.  Our previous method simply used the output of the 'svnlook' command in a perl script to count everything.  I've tried using the output 'svnlook changed' to build a count, and it mostly works, but there is some rather annoying guesswork involved.  As a side note, the repos are hosted on a xen vm, so I/O performance is a bit of an issue. Anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: I am interested in tackling this issue. Would you mind sharing the Perl script you were using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about server side repos.

`svn list -R --xml file:///svnrepos/myrepo | grep kind=\"file\" | wc -l`

its not very fast, but it is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into the `svnadmin` dump delta format. I've played with it a little, but basically it's one huge patch-type file containing all the files and all the revisions. It's text in nature, so relatively straightforward to process with something like Perl, and it is fairly small compared to going through the whole of each revision one at a time.

You'd probably need to have a representation of all the files (if 4 million, maybe use SQLite for this) and update them as you pass through each revision. The delta does the revisions in order, so it ought to be relatively straightforward. (Maybe I am being optimistic.)

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

```
find /svndir | wc -l
```

The output from find on Linux or Unix generates one line per file or directory, and it is recursive.  Pipe the output to "wc -l" to count the lines.

Comment: Based on the OP context this would be counting files in the server-side repo, which does not have a file for each "file" in the repo. The above command would count the db, conf, dav, and other files that track the meta of the repo.